# Is this the right way to detect connection to a WiFi network?

Tags: android-wifi

I'm making an application for Android that needs to react to when the device gets connected to a WiFi network, I'm currently trying to implement it using a BroadcastReceiver to monitor android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION - is this way correct, or is there a way that would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jase, You need to register to receive `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`. The intent has a `NetworkInfo` extra. Examine it to find its state. If the state is `NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED`, then you are connected to a network.

For sample code on achieving this, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6595734/570930).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)

> Broadcast intent action indicating
>   that Wi-Fi has been enabled, disabled,
>   enabling, disabling, or unknown. One
>   extra provides this state as an int.
>   Another extra provides the previous
>   state, if available.

and [WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)

> Broadcast intent action indicating
>   that a connection to the supplicant
>   has been established (and it is now
>   possible to perform Wi-Fi operations)
>   or the connection to the supplicant
>   has been lost. One extra provides the
>   connection state as a boolean, where
>   true means CONNECTED.

Read from the broadcast or do a check when you get any of them like:

```
WifiManager wifi=(WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
int state=wifi.getWifiState();
```

Now you can check *state*, it will be one of

- WIFI_STATE_DISABLED
- WIFI_STATE_DISABLING
- **WIFI_STATE_ENABLED**  <-- With this you can send/receive data
- WIFI_STATE_ENABLING
- WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN