# Broadcast reveiver for detecting availability of a new network

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-networking

I am looking to find an intent action that is fired when a new network is detected on your android phone. Is thea any? I have checked the documentation, the only one that is close is `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` I want to write a Broadcast receiver that listens to a new network detected. Alternatively is there like volatile a content provider for the networks your android phone detects?
Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to be informed when your Android device connects to a new network? In that case you need to use `NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`. [This question at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595734/wifi-state-changed-action-intent-not-received-upon-connection-to-wifi-access-poin/6741489#6741489) deals with something similar (specific to WiFi though). You might find something similar to deal with a higher abstraction (i.e, Network in place of Wifi).

If you want to be informed when a new network (i.e, AP) is visible to your Android device, try looking at `WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION`.

Comment: Thanx WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION was what I was looking for.

Comment: If the answer helped you, you should consider "accepting" it or upvoting it.