# WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION is never fired

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I am registering receiver on `onResume()`:

```
registerReceiver(wifiConnectivityReceiver, new
                IntentFilter(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION));
```

This is the receiver itself :

```
class WiFiConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_CONNECTED,false)){
            Log.d(TAG,"Connected to network!");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG,"Could not connect to network!");
        }
    }
}
```

In my application I am able to connect to selected WiFi network,but this `SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION` is never fired.If I change it to `SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` for example it is working.

I am working on ICS.
Did someone else experience problems like this with this intent?

Comment: Why don't you use `NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` ?

Comment: yes, use `NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`with intended effects: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6741489/1977815

Answer (score 4):

I thing that the following code will help you:

```
public void installMyReceiver(){
    if (I) Log.i(TAG, "installMyReceiver() - Online");
    mFlag = true;


    myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent){
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){

                SupplicantState supplicantState = (SupplicantState)intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NEW_STATE);
                if (supplicantState == (SupplicantState.COMPLETED)){
                    if (I) Log.i(TAG, "SUPPLICANTSTATE ---> Connected");
                      //do something
                }

                if (supplicantState == (SupplicantState.DISCONNECTED)){
                    if (I) Log.i(TAG, "SUPPLICANTSTATE ---> Disconnected");
                       //do something
                }

            }
        }
    };

    IntentFilter mFilter = new IntentFilter (WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    this.registerReceiver (myReceiver, mFilter);
}
```

It's a simple way to obtain the information which you want and then execute some action.
I hope it can help you!

Answer (score 0):

> Did someone else experience problems like this with this intent?

Yes, me. It seems that on some devices the intent is never declared by the operating system. (Yes, I did factory-reset the device.) I ended up to additionally add a watchdog counter to check `WifiManager.isWifiEnabled()` to become aware of changes. Of course, this will always be a bit delayed.

Don’t forget to remove the callback *to the same instance* of the `Runnable` from the `Handler` in your `BroadcastReceiver` again if you do this, for not handling the event twice if your code executes on a device that *does* declare the intent.